# Fetch result in case of many to many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, hibernate-mapping, foreign-key-relationship

I have three tables

1. employee: storing employee information
2. role_description: storing types of role i have like admin, zone manger, country manager
3. employee_role_details: having many to many relationship from employee and role description with some extra fields.

Now I am facing an issue in fetching result that contains (employee_id, email) from employee table, (role_ownership, role_id) from employee_role_details and (role_name and role_description)from role_description corresponding to role_id in role_description.

Employee.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee", uniqueConstraints= @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"employee_email"}))
public class Employee {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "employee_id")
    private long employeeId;

    @Column(name = "employee_name")
    private String employeeName;

    @Column(name = "employee_email", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String employeeEmail;

    @Column(name = "contact_no")
    private String contactNo;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "is_active")
    private Boolean isActive = true;

    @Transient
    private long EmployeeRoleId;

    @Transient
    private String roleName;

    @Transient
    private int totalpage;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    //@JsonIgnore
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "employeeRoleRecord-employee")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<EmployeeRoleRecord> roleRecords = new ArrayList<>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "assignedTo", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "complaint-treatment-employee")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<ComplaintsCategory> complaintCategoryAssignedTo = new ArrayList<>();
```

EmployeeDescription.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "role_description")
public class RoleDescription {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "role_id")
    private long roleId;

    @Column(name = "role_name")
    private String roleName;

    @Column(name = "role_description")
    private String roleDescription;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private boolean status;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "description", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonManagedReference(value = "employeeRoleRecord-roleDescription")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<EmployeeRoleRecord> roleRecords = new ArrayList<EmployeeRoleRecord>();
```

EmployeeRoleRecord

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "employee_role_record")
public class EmployeeRoleRecord {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "employee_role_id")
    private long employeeRoleId;

    @Column(name = "role_ownership")
    private String roleOwnership;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private boolean status = true;


    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference(value = "employeeRoleRecord-employee")
    @JoinColumn(name = "employee_id")
    private Employee employee;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonBackReference(value = "employeeRoleRecord-roleDescription")
    @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
    private RoleDescription description;

    @Transient
    private long roleId;
```

Code inside a  dao

```
public Employee getEmployeeByEmail(String email) {
        return (Employee) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                .createCriteria(Employee.class)
                .add(Restrictions.eq("employeeEmail", email)).uniqueResult();
    }
```

services:

```
public Employee getSurveyData(String employeeEmail){

        Employee loggedInEmployee =
                 loginDao.getEmployeeByEmail(employeeEmail);

        Employee  loggedInEmployeeRecord = new Employee();

            loggedInEmployeeRecord.setEmployeeId(loggedInEmployee.getEmployeeId());
            loggedInEmployeeRecord.setEmployeeName(loggedInEmployee.getEmployeeName());

            List<EmployeeRoleRecord> employeeRoleRecords = loggedInEmployee.getRoleRecords();

            List<EmployeeRoleRecord> employeeRoleRecord = new  ArrayList<>();

            for(EmployeeRoleRecord record :  employeeRoleRecords){

                EmployeeRoleRecord employeeRole = new EmployeeRoleRecord();

                employeeRole.setRoleId(record.getDescription().getRoleId());
                employeeRole.setRoleName(record.getDescription().getRoleName());
                employeeRole.setRoleOwnership(record.getRoleOwnership());
                employeeRole.setStatus(record.isStatus());
                employeeRoleRecord.add(employeeRole);
            }

            loggedInEmployeeRecord.setRoleRecords(employeeRoleRecord);


         return loggedInEmployee;
    }
```

Output:

```
    {
  "employeeId": 1,
  "employeeName": "Dhyanandra Singh",
  "employeeEmail": "admin",
  "contactNo": "9893651872",
  "password": "123456",
  "isActive": true,
  "roleRecords": [
    {
      "employeeRoleId": 1,
      "roleOwnership": "overall project",
      "status": true,
      "roleId": 0,
      "roleName": null
    }
  ],
}
```

problem:

json output i'm getting is not containing role id and role name in  role records list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is:

Your roleId attribute on EmployeeRoleRecord classe is mapped as @Transient, which means that it is not persisted on database, so Hibernate is not able to fetch the result of this field.

Looking at your classes modeling I couldn't figure out exactly what you are trying to map with the roleId, I suggest two possible approaches:

1. Do not return directly your query on getEmployeeByEmail method. First get the results, then iterate it and set manually the desired roleId you want on each record;
2. Check your model scheme and make the correct mapping for roleId, it probably should reference another entity, so make sure to map the relationship correctly to get your results on a single query.

Good luck.

Comment: in EmployeeRoleRecord i have many to one mapping exists as RoleDescription contains roleId.

Comment: I already tried approach 1 you have mentioned but i didn't get roleId in it may be because it is foreign key.

Comment: For Hibernate roleId is NOT a foreign key, since you are using "@Transient" annotation. As I said before, you should make the correct mappings for roleId, otherwise you will not be able to get it's value when obtaining the JSON.

Comment: already have a mapping          @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
@JsonBackReference(value = "employeeRoleRecord-roleDescription") @JoinColumn(name = "role_id")
private RoleDescription description;

    @Transient
    private long roleId;

Comment: If my answer has helped you, please can you mark it as correct answer or upvote it? Anyways, glad to hear your problem was solved! Hibernate can be quite frustrating sometimes...

Answer (score 0):

added transient roleId and roleName in EmployeeRoleRecord then having some modification in services. like iterating list setting roleId and roleName in it.

```
public Employee getSurveyData(String employeeEmail){

            Employee loggedInEmployee =
                     loginDao.getEmployeeByEmail(employeeEmail);

            Employee  loggedInEmployeeRecord = new Employee();

                loggedInEmployeeRecord.setEmployeeId(loggedInEmployee.getEmployeeId());
                loggedInEmployeeRecord.setEmployeeName(loggedInEmployee.getEmployeeName());
                loggedInEmployeeRecord.setEmployeeEmail(loggedInEmployee.getEmployeeEmail());
                loggedInEmployeeRecord.setContactNo(loggedInEmployee.getContactNo());

                List<EmployeeRoleRecord> employeeRoleRecords = loggedInEmployee.getRoleRecords();

                List<EmployeeRoleRecord> employeeRoleRecord = new  ArrayList<>();

                for(EmployeeRoleRecord record :  employeeRoleRecords){

                    EmployeeRoleRecord employeeRole = new EmployeeRoleRecord();

                    employeeRole.setEmployeeRoleId(employeeRole.getEmployeeRoleId());
                    employeeRole.setRoleId(record.getDescription().getRoleId());
                    employeeRole.setRoleName(record.getDescription().getRoleName());
                    employeeRole.setRoleOwnership(record.getRoleOwnership());
                    employeeRole.setStatus(record.isStatus());
                    employeeRoleRecord.add(employeeRole);
                }

                loggedInEmployeeRecord.setRoleRecords(employeeRoleRecord);


             return loggedInEmployeeRecord;
        }
```